# Получение курса доллара с XML

Tags: php, xml

по данной ссылке `http://www.nbkr.kg/XML/daily.xml` c помощью PHP мне нужно получить только курс USD, а именно сами числа (которые в теге Value).

подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать

Comment: вам готовый скрипт написать?

Comment: скачать xml в файл и его обработать.. Там конкретно USD указано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получить данные из xml в с помощью php можно следующим образом:

```
<?php
// получаем с помощью curl или иным способом
$res = <<<HTML
<CurrencyRates Name="Daily Exchange Rates" Date="21.12.2018"><Currency ISOCode="USD"><Nominal>1</Nominal><Value>69,8381</Value></Currency><Currency ISOCode="EUR"><Nominal>1</Nominal><Value>79,7970</Value></Currency><Currency ISOCode="KZT"><Nominal>1</Nominal><Value>0,1883</Value></Currency><Currency ISOCode="RUB"><Nominal>1</Nominal><Value>1,0366</Value></Currency></CurrencyRates>
HTML;

$currencies = new SimpleXMLElement($res);

function findCurrency($arr, $currencyCode)
{
    $idx = 0;
    $find = false;
    while (!$find && ($idx < count($arr))) {
        if ($arr[$idx]->attributes()['ISOCode'] == $currencyCode) {
            $find = true;
            $searchResult = $arr[$idx]->Value;
        }
        $idx++;
    }

    return isset($searchResult)
        ? $searchResult
        : false;
}

echo findCurrency($currencies->Currency, 'USD');
```

Comment: Если мой ответ ответил на вопрос, то прошу отметить его как правильный. Это поможет другим участникам быстрее находить правильные ответы на свои вопросы.

Comment: @eustatos зачем такие огороды кода для задач решаемых в несколько строк? Смотри мой вариант. Может стоит быть проще? ;)

Comment: @Nsk, а если валют много? Хорошо валют не может быть очень много ) Но все равно лишнего не хочется пробегать в цикле.

Comment: @eustatos, нашел баксы делай break; и не бегай лишнего в цикле.

Answer (score 3):

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file('http://www.nbkr.kg/XML/daily.xml');

foreach($xml as $item){
    if($item->attributes()['ISOCode']=='USD')   echo $item->Value;
}
```